# Pointer bounds and pointer arithmetic in SQLite source code

Tags: c, sqlite, pointers

I was browsing through the SQLite source code when I came across this function starting at line `387` in `shell.c`.

Source code: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

The function in question:

```
/*
** Determines if a string is a number of not.
*/
static int isNumber(const char *z, int *realnum){
  if( *z=='-' || *z=='+' ) z++;
  if( !IsDigit(*z) ){
    return 0;
  }
  z++;
  if( realnum ) *realnum = 0;
  while( IsDigit(*z) ){ z++; }
  if( *z=='.' ){
    z++;
    if( !IsDigit(*z) ) return 0;
    while( IsDigit(*z) ){ z++; }
    if( realnum ) *realnum = 1;
  }
  if( *z=='e' || *z=='E' ){
    z++;
    if( *z=='+' || *z=='-' ) z++;
    if( !IsDigit(*z) ) return 0;
    while( IsDigit(*z) ){ z++; }
    if( realnum ) *realnum = 1;
  }
  return *z==0;
}
```

Note: IsDigit is a macro, which feeds an unsigned character into isdigit defined in ctype.

```
#define IsDigit(X)  isdigit((unsigned char)X)
```

The function and pointer use makes sense to me, however, the first two lines leads me to believe they may be used improperly based on my understanding.

They use pointer arithmetic to shuffle through the string.

```
if( *z=='-' || *z=='+' ) z++;
```

If the char at the first position of the pointer is a '-' or '+', move the pointer over one position. However, this does not seem to take into account if the string passed into the function only has one character that happens to be a '-' or '+' symbol.

```
if( !IsDigit(*z) ){
```

When 'z' is dereferenced, isn't this corrupted/illegal memory access because it goes out of the bounds of the pointer, or is there something behind the scenes with pointer arithmetic that stops this from happening?

Comment: SQLite is used on *hundreds of millions* iOS and Android devices every day. Chances are, you haven't found a previously undiscovered bug in their fundamental number parsing.

Answer (score 1):

No, C strings are expected to be null terminated.

If you pass a string containing only a `-` or `+` character, the `z` pointer will point to the null terminator after being incremented, and `IsDigit(*z)` will be equivalent to `IsDigit(0)`, which will evaluate to `false` and return 0.

Comment: This makes sense, but 'IsDigit(0)' would evaluate to 'true' because 0 is defined as a digit.

Comment: No, the *character* `'0'` (numeric value 48 in ASCII) will be recognized as a digit. The terminating NUL (numeric value 0) will not.